# Excel vba - Userform - doesn't change output - focus worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to use excel vba userforms to automate many tasks in a spreadsheet.  There is a Button1 on Sheet1 that has two commands.

```
sub Button1_click()
  sheet1.range("a3").select
  userform1.show
end sub
```

As an example there is a data entry worksheet (sheet2) that we want to switch to  to input data values to a list.

To simplify in this example and to show my issue the userform has one button

```
sub CommandButton1_click()
  userform1.hide ' hide the form
  sheet2.activate
  sheet2.range("b2").select
end sub
```

What I want to be able to do is use the user form button to switch to sheet2, select b2, and be able to enter data starting there immediately.

What I've been getting is a selection box on sheet2.range("b2") BUT I show color starting at sheet1!a3, then sheet1!b4,... I have entry occurring on sheet1!b2 etc.

[image: First of three]

Shows beginning and entry

[image: Second of three]

Entry colors from sheet1 showing on visible sheet2 - data not appearing

[image: Third of three]

Actual data is entered on sheet1 not sheet2 -

Comment: Do you have any code anywhere (in the UserForm, or in either of the sheets) which is doing the coloring?

Comment: No the coloring is done by hand.  It was only done to show what was underneath.

Comment: I can see the problem now.  (But I can't see the **reason** for it.)  Although `Sheet2` has been activated, user interactions are being processed against `Sheet1`.

Comment: A workaround is to add a line `Debug.Print "workaround"` just after `UserForm1.Show`.  It seems to get Excel to realise that it needs to refresh things.

Comment: @YowE3K I don't understand the problem :-(  ...or, can't repro with Excel 2010.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I was using 2013 and reproduced.  The problem seems to be, with the user's code on a button in the worksheet and on a button in a form, after clicking both buttons you are presented with Sheet2, but anything you type only appears on Sheet2 until you "refresh" it by going back to Sheet1 (where you see all the data you entered) and then going back to Sheet2 (where none of the changes appear).  (And my "workaround" of performing a `Debug.Print` seems to fix the problem.  Really weird.)

Comment: @Mat'sMug Thanks for looking anyway.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Note: I don't get the exact same behaviour as appears in the OP's screenshots.  When I do it, the things I type appear to be where I type them, and stay there.  Things only start "appearing" weird when I switch sheets and realise that what I typed appeared in the same positions but on the other sheet, and switch back shows a blank sheet where I thought I had been typing.

Comment: This is a similar issue (no real answer here either)... [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36768134/excel-vba-worksheet-focus)

Comment: @YowE3K - What I 'basically' understand is happening is that when the userform calling subroutine 'sub Button1_click()' ends, it returns input "focus" (I don't know what else to call it- if you do please tell me) to the sheet it was called from. If I create a new worksheet (Sheet3) and copy the button to it, the same behavior occurs on that worksheet as on sheet1. I can't get the debug.print to fix the problem. If you can suggest a different method, I'm game. Thanks for your time and interest.

Comment: @EvanJ Hmmm - I was sure that `Debug.Print` worked yesterday, but it isn't working form me today.  And, yes, I would say this question and the one you linked to are identical.  (I see no-one managed to solve it either :( )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be (as you mention in the comments) that, at the end of `Button1_Click`, the focus returns to the sheet containing the button even though the `ActiveSheet` is now a different sheet.

For the moment (until someone comes up with a better solution) a "workaround" is to allow the `Button1_Click` event to finish running before showing the Form.  That can be achieved by changing `Button1_Click` to something like:

```
Sub Button1_click()
  Sheet1.Range("a3").Select
  Application.OnTime Now(), "BypassBug"
End Sub

Sub BypassBug()
  UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: THANK you!  (Sorry no rep for you- my account rep is still too low...) This works for me in the larger application too.  I'm guessing it some kind of race condition where one part of the process assumes the other part is finished, and then does it's part too soon.

Comment: @EvanJ The "accept" itself gives me rep, a huge +15 to add to take me up to 20286 (and you get +2 as well), but the main thing is the fun involved in solving the puzzle! :D

Comment: I like puzzles too, but I don't like them with deadlines... ;-)